# How to send data from Arduino to PHP web page

Tags: php, arduino, html, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I am working on a web based irrigation system, and I need temperature and humidity for the same; I am using sensor: DHT11 for that, and I am getting output in the Arduino IDE, but I want it on my website (i.e. a PHP webpage).

How can I do it? I have refereed to this [link](http://www.instructables.com/id/PART-1-Send-Arduino-data-to-the-Web-PHP-MySQL-D3js/) but I am neither getting any error nor any output.

Comment: Provide the code you have so far, otherwise there is no way to help you with this question.

Answer (score 2):

Refer this link
[Posting data from arduino to php](http://www.instructables.com/id/PART-1-Send-Arduino-data-to-the-Web-PHP-MySQL-D3js/)

Below is the jist of sending data to server

```
 h = (int) dht.readHumidity();
 t = (int) dht.readTemperature();
 data = "temp=" + String(t) + "&hum=" + String(h);

if (client.connect("your server ip",80)) 
{ // REPLACE WITH YOUR SERVER   ADDRESS
  client.println("POST filepath.php HTTP/1.1"); 
  client.println("Host: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"); // SERVER ADDRESS HERE TOO
  client.println("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
  client.print("Content-Length: "); 
  client.println(data.length()); 
  client.println(); 
  client.print(data); 
}
```

On the other hand, you have to create a server side script.

Comment: to which page does it send the data is it the index page or which page?
Also can you elaborate more on this line please:
`client.println("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");`
What does the application/x-www-form-urlencoded do?

Answer (score 1):

1- Make sure you have an Apache server on your machine if you are testing it locally.
2-you need to setup a SQL DB , 
3- create your PHP scripts which will call the PHP script:
for example 
*client.println("GET /ethernetSend/index.php?baynumber="+Bay+"&vacant="+vacant+"&submit=Send+Sensorvalues HTTP/1.1");*

you may refer to the Web client example by David A. Mellis
it will be more than a start point for you.